# EF Core: fetch two SELECT statements in a single call by FromSql()

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the following SP in which a number of rows and the total number of rows are fetched. How is it possible to call the SP and fetch its content (the 2 SELECT's)?

```
-- A very simple SP
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sample
AS 
BEGIN

SELECT TOP 10 c.Id, s.CreationDate, s.FirstName, s.LastName
FROM Some_Table s
ORDER BY s.CreationDate

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Some_Table s as TotalRecord    

END
```

I know it is possible to use Dapper or other ORMs, but I am going to use the EF Core 2.2

Comment: What you're talking about is multiple results, which I don't think is supported currently (although I'm not sure if in your case the second result being a scalar simplifies this): https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do in this case

-- A very simple SP
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sample
AS 
BEGIN
Declare @TotalCount int
SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(*) 
FROM Some_Table s as TotalRecord

SELECT TOP 10 @TotalCount as TotalCount, c.Id, s.CreationDate, s.FirstName, s.LastName
FROM Some_Table s
ORDER BY s.CreationDate

END

Comment: How do you get EF core to retrieve both results?

Comment: There would only be one result now, just access the TotalCount. You can add the totalcount  to your model that is returned. Does that make sense?